# Calculate Next Acceptable Notification Time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time

Good evening!

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the next time it's acceptable to notify someone based upon their previously stored preferences - basically, they specify what days of the week they wish to be notified along with a time range. For instance, someone might want to be notified Monday - Friday between the hours of 9 AM and 5 PM. In other words, only notify them during the work week and only during normal business hours.

If I generate an alert at, say Saturday morning at 4 AM, I want to arrive at the following Monday at 9 AM. On the other hand, if I generate an alert at 2:30 PM on Wednesday, the function should return the current date and time - Wednesday at 2:30 PM. I'm not worried about holidays and I'm absolutely fine with a single time frame for all seven days of the week.

It really feels like this should be straightforward, but I have as of yet not been able to figure out a way to do so. Anyone ever solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!
Marshall

Comment: Not really a programming question. But word of advice: instead of generating the alert at a previous time, generate it on the right time. Whatever the programming language, the basic application design you're going for is a scheduler. Save their preferences in a database or flat file or whatever, every day or every hour check for users that match the current day and hour, and then generate the alert. This is the basic premise of scheduled emails for reporting, for example, in some companies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood Jerome's comment, but it probably indicates that I did not explain my question too terribly well. Hopefully, my answer will help that!

I spent some time this morning and believe I have a solution worked out - feels a bit on the sloppy side, but every test I throw at it comes out as expected.

A few notes - mon1, tue1, etc. are all check boxes on my test UI. If mon1 is checked, that indicates the recipient is willing to receive an alert on Monday between the hours of start1 and stop 1, which are datetimepicker controls on the test UI, allowing for indicating time of day.

```
    internal class ADOW
    {
        public DayOfWeek dow;
        public bool allowed;

        public ADOW(DayOfWeek dw, bool allw)
        {
            dow = dw;
            allowed = allw;
        }
    }

    private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ADOW> allowedDOW = new List<ADOW>();
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Monday, mon1.Checked));
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, tue1.Checked));
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, wed1.Checked));
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Thursday, thu1.Checked));
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Friday, fri1.Checked));
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Saturday, sat1.Checked));
        allowedDOW.Add(new ADOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday, sun1.Checked));

        DateTime cdt = currentDT.Value;
        DayOfWeek cdow = cdt.DayOfWeek;
        bool todayOK = allowedDOW.Find(x => x.dow == cdow).allowed;

        if (todayOK)
        {
            // Check to see if the current time is inside the acceptable range
            double secondsStart = start1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
            double secondsStop = stop1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;

            double secondsNow = cdt.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;

            if (secondsNow>=secondsStart)
            {
                if (secondsNow<=secondsStop)
                {
                    // Now is ok, send the alert immediately
                    SendIt(cdt);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Too late in the day - find the next valid day
                    cdt = LookAhead(cdt, allowedDOW);
                    SendIt(cdt);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The day is right, but it's too early - schedule the send for the now + (secondsStart-now)
                SendIt(cdt.AddSeconds(secondsStart - secondsNow));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // This particular day is no good - find an acceptable one
            cdt = LookAhead(cdt, allowedDOW);
            SendIt(cdt);
        }

    }

    private DateTime LookAhead(DateTime cdt, List<ADOW> adow)
    {
        DateTime response = DateTime.MinValue;

        bool acceptable = false;
        while (!acceptable)
        {
            // First, add 24 hours to the current time to push the day by one.
            cdt = cdt.AddHours(24);

            // Now, we need to set the right time of day, which is start1.
            double secondsOver = cdt.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds - start1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
            cdt = cdt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)secondsOver));

            // Finally, check to see if the new day of the week is valid - if not, keep looking!
            acceptable = adow.Find(x => x.dow == cdt.DayOfWeek).allowed;

            if (acceptable)
            {
                response = cdt;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Thanks for reading! Looking forward to anyone pointing out any flaws or improvements.

Marshall

Comment: By the way, no real error checking in the code - need to make sure notifications are allowed at least one day of the week. Furthermore, I should ensure that stop time is after start time! Fairly trivial , just wasn't the priority.